# JMeter Thread Group in Workbench

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying running JMeter on command line(-n).

I did just run. But my temporary thread group in workbench is executed.

Is it specification?

How do I not execute temporary thread group ?(I would not like to remove)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can disable it.

Are you sure it is executed? can you show your test plan ?

Comment: Sorry, Response is late. "Disable" I have found it Just now !! Thank you so much.